# Render quarto to HTML specifying output location lacks plots and style

Tags: r, quarto

I am trying to render a `.qmd` file to HTML specifying an output file. I am compiling it from a Quarto Project from RStudio on MacOS 12.6. I also have a bootstrap theme in the YAML header.

```yaml
---
title: "quarto_output_experiment"
format:
  html:
    theme: journal
---
```

If I render it with `Cmd + Shift + K` from RStudio, the HTML document appears in the same directory as the `.qmd` and looks fine. However if I render it from the Quarto CLI specifying the output directory (a folder called `output`), the HTML can't render plots and lacks any sort of formatting and style. The command is

`quarto render quarto_output_experiment.qmd --output output/report.html`

Here are the results.

| This is when rendered from RStudio | This is when render via Quarto CLI |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Nice HTML] | [image: Broken HTML] |

> What am I missing? How can I render the HTML in a different directory and have plots and proper style?

For reference, this is the document itself

````
---
title: "quarto_output_experiment"
format:
  html:
    theme: journal
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document.
To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

```{r}
1 + 1
```

# Lorem ipsum

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(100)), aes(x)) + geom_density()
```
````

### UPDATE

Specifying `--output-dir` intead of `--output` produces a document with plots and style, but the question still remains if there is a way to change the name of the output HTML file? Probably not mission critical, but I'm still curious.

Comment: What quarto version Are you using?

Comment: I was using 0.9. I just upgraded to 1.1.251 and the same thing happens

Answer (score 5):

That is a really weird bug and it seems to be related to the path (see [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2266). Usually, you can use `quarto::render_quarto()` like this,

```
quarto::quarto_render(input = "quarto_output_experiment.qmd", output_file = "report.html")
```

This works, but when you add the folder name

```
quarto::quarto_render(input = "quarto_output_experiment.qmd", output_file = "results/report.html")
```

it does not work anymore. The problem is that the folder (`quarto_output_experiment_files`) where the libs and images are stored, is not automatically also placed where the output-file is located.

I would file an issue [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues).

A possible solution for the time being would be the `self-contained` param that produces self-contained html files, e.g.

```
---
title: "quarto_output_experiment"
format:
  html:
    theme: journal
    self-contained: true  
---
```

then you could use `file.copy` to move that file in the correct folder.

**Edit**: The option `self-contained` is depreciated, use `embed-resources` instead! [Link](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/html.html#rendering)